# Spring Transaction - noRollbackFor won't commit when exception occurs

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rollback

I want that if i get an E-Mail Exception, to NOT rollback the transaction.

I am using `HibernateTransactionManager` and

```
set  property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"
```

because i have nested transactions.

Also because i call `this.getService()` i have set

`lookup-method name="getService" bean="enrollmentProcessorService"` .

This way i should get the Spring Proxy.

But if exceptions occurs, the transaction is still rolledback.
my code looks like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void processConfirmation() throws SystemException {
        //do something
        this.getService().processConfirmationData(as400ContractId);


}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = {MailException.class})
public void processConfirmationData(final long as400ContractDataId) throws SystemException {
    final AS400ContractData as400ContractData = this.readAS400ContractData(as400ContractDataId, false);

    this.populateEnrollmentOptionAnswers(as400ContractData.getContractData());

    final PersonalData personalData = this.readPersonalData(as400ContractData.getContractData()
            .getEpiphanyPersonalData().getPersonalData().getId(), true);

    try {
        personalData.setConfirmMailSent(true);
        as400ContractData.getContractData().getEpiphanyPersonalData().getPersonalData().setConfirmMailSent(true);
        this.personalDataDAO.flush();
        this.emailService.sendConfirmationMailToLOI(as400ContractData); //commit if exception is thrown here
    } catch (final DataAccessException dae) {
        LOGGER.error(CANNOT_UPDATE_PERSONAL_DATA_OBJECT, dae);
        throw new SystemException(StringUtils.EMPTY, CANNOT_UPDATE_PERSONAL_DATA_OBJECT, dae);
    } catch (final MessagingException e) {
        LOGGER.error(CANNOT_SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL, e);
        throw new SystemException(StringUtils.EMPTY, CANNOT_SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL, e);
    } catch (final MailException e) {
        Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();
        System.out.println("caught");
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you catch the exception, so there is no way the Spring interceptor can see it and rollback the transaction.

And then, even if you didn't catch it, you've configured the method with `**no**RollbackFor = {MailException.class}`. This means that you **don't** want a rollback if this exception is thrown. Use `rollbackFor = {MailException.class}` instead.

Comment: I did a horrible mistake. I wanted to say that i want my transaction to commit for that exception

Comment: Make sure that the lookup method does indeed return a proxy, and that the transaction interceptor does create a new transaction. Or refactor the code and put the requires_new method in another bean. But if the emailService is itself transactional, and throws the exception, then its method is the one that must be marked with noRollbackFor.

Comment: Last remark from @JBNizet was my problem. I used `noRollbackFor` on the wrong method. It needs to be the method where you *throw* the exception, not where you catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get exception, current transaction is rollbacked. No rollback rules, for those times when you do not want a transaction to be marked for rollback when an exception is thrown. Try to remove noRollbackFor annotation.

Also you should rethrow exception. Don't catch MailException.

Comment: Correction: Whenever you get a **runtime** exception, current transaction is rollbacked.

Comment: Yes, that's right. EJB provide UserTransaction annotation. Probably there is something similar in Spring

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I encountered the same problem.

When I saw the source :org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#invoke.

I found where the problem is.

**this.emailService.sendConfirmationMailToLOI**   is another Service, so the TransactionAttribute is new.

you can fix this problem :
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, noRollbackFor = {MailException.class})
In this method（emailService.sendConfirmationMailToLOI*）, the configuration above